# Passing comments_id to controller in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, edit, destroy

I am unable to edit/delete comments in a basic Rails MVC, but the trouble I'm having is that the comments_controller looks for the user_id and not the comments_id, because the user_id is the foreign key. My assumption was that Comment.find(params[:id]) would lead to comments_id, but this is npot the case.

This is the last part of my comments_controller:

```
    def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user
end

def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user
    @comment.update(comment_params)
    redirect_to @comment
end

def destroy
    @user = current_user
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to comments_path
end 

private
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :location, :title, :body)
end
```

The comments in the views that I'm trying to edit/delete look like this:

```
     <% @user.comments.each do |w| %>
    <tr>
      <td>Location:<%= w.location %></td>       
      <td>Title:<%= w.title %></td>
      <td>Body:<%= w.body %></td>  
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment_path,
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td><br>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks for any advice offered :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit/destroy your comment, you need to pass the actual comment in the `link_to` helper. Something like `link_to 'Destroy', w, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` will do.

Similarly with edit: `link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(w)`

Comment: Yes! It worked - but only the second way you suggested, with the w in brackets directly behind the path :-)